# Can you access previous /var files from new compiles of the same app?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, file-io

Our app downloads a bunch of video files and allows the user to view them. We've noticed that we can download and play the files with no issues at all. But then if an update is pushed or we use Xcode to push a new app over the old one (same version) it will report that the video cannot be found. This is despite the the fact that we can see the video there, in the same folder and folder ID we're looking for has not changed. Is there something happening behind the scenes with local storage for iOS app files that makes them inaccessible after an update?

Example:

/var/mobile/containers/data/application/{same id}/documents/

Comment: How are you creating/storing the location in the file system of your files?  The part of the path that you refer to as "{same id}" in your question can change at any time, so assuming that it will always be the same would cause your issue.

Comment: With the video files, we store a JSON file which contains a path to all the video files. We successfully read in that JSON file (same path) but when we attempt to stream the video which sits beside it, it fails. We're still investigating but from what we can tell it looks as though the act of reading the path from the JSON file makes it fail for some reason. If we construct the same path internally instead of reading it, it works. That's consistent with your suggestion that it changes all the time. Maybe we were unsuccessfully reading old (but still existing) data.

Comment: Try show data from json file on screen and check this info